# Is this expected value evaluated correctly?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $p$ be a probability of appearing lower side of coin and $q=1-p$ be a probability of appearing upper side of coin. We throw the coin to the moment $N$ of appearing the lower side twice in the last two throws. I am obliged to find expected value of random variable $N$ (for example if $N=3$ then the lower side of coin would appear in the second and third throw).

**My solution:**

I used of course the definition of expected value for discrete case
$$EX=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i p_i.   $$
For random variable $N$ we have
$EN=1\cdot 0 +2\cdot p\cdot p+3\cdot q\cdot p\cdot  p+4\cdot 1  \cdot  q\cdot p \cdot p+\ldots=\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty}i q p^2 .$

If this reasoning is correct is it possible to somehow evaluate the series which I recieved? I do not know if it is final solution.

Comment: The term having $4$ is wrong, there could be $4 \cdot p \cdot q \cdot p \cdot p$ as well, which doesn't have consecutive up side falls till the fourth turn. Do you know Markov chains? Or else you will need a recursion here.

Comment: "I used of course the definition of expected value for discrete case..." If you are asked to find an expectation then never start with finding it on base of the distribution (as you did in your effort). First seek for other ways. Quite often expectations are much easyer to find than distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented your approach is not okay.

**Hint**:

Let $Y$ denote the number of trials needed to arrive at the first upper side.

Then:$$\mathbb EN=$$$$P(Y=1)\mathbb E[N|Y=1]+P(Y=2)\mathbb E[N|Y=2]+P(Y>2)\mathbb E[N|Y>2]\tag1$$
Here:

- $\mathbb E[N|Y=1]=1+\mathbb EN$
- $\mathbb E[N|Y=2]=2+\mathbb EN$
- $\mathbb E[N|Y>2]=2$

(do you see why?)

Combined with the info mentioned in the bullets equality $(1)$ enables you to find $\mathbb EN$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I don't see why we have $\mathbb{E}[N|Y=2]=2+\mathbb{E}N$. Is this from the fact that we should obtain in the first throw the lower side and in the second the upper so the probabilities each of them is equal to $1$? Beside this, I have one more question: am I right that $P(Y=1)=p$, $P(Y=2)=q\cdot p$ and $P(Y>2)=1-p-q\cdot p$?

Comment: $Y=2$ if and only if we start with $LU$. You can interpreted that as: "our first effort to arrive at LL failed, and now we are back in our original situation". Then we start with a new effort with two failures in our pocket. So you could say that the distribution of $N$ under condition $Y=2$ is the same as the distribution of $2+N$. That's why $\mathbb E[N\mid Y=2]=\mathbb E[2+N]=2+\mathbb EN$. Here $P(Y=1)=q$ (not $p$), $P(Y=2)=pq$ and $P(Y>2)=1-q-pq$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is clear. In $P(Y=1)$ there was a soft mistake.